# Simple Element Positioning in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

This is one my first ventures into the world of iOS development. I am trying to make a simple app where a big ball pushes around a little ball. I have been reading a couple tutorials and I am stuck at the very first point. Please let me know if I'm doing anything crazy (which I probably am). Any suggestions at all will be hugely appreciated. The following code is located in my init function:

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player.png" 
                                               rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2 + 10, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player]; 



        CCSprite *ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" 
                                               rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
        ball.position = ccp((player.contentSize.width/2 + 10)+ball.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:ball];
```

The player is the bigger ball of course. I would guess that this code should put both balls in the vertical center of the screen. But what I get is this:

[image]

Why is the second ball's center lower than the bigger ball's center? It was my understanding that you should consider the dead center of the sprite to be the point at which you position the sprite and that winSize.height / 2 should put both sprites in the vertical middle. I am defining the sizes (I think) as 40x40 and 20x20, I made sure that these images are exactly this size.

If you see anything on an unrelated note about my code, please suggest a better / more efficient way of doing things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is referenced to the upper left-hand corner. If you change your code to this, both should be centered (notice subtracting half of the height). You may need to change the size for the rect to match the actual size of the .png's if they aren't the same.

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player.png" 
                                           rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2 + 10, winSize.height/2 - player.contentSize.height/2);
[self addChild:player]; 



CCSprite *ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" 
                                           rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
ball.position = ccp((player.contentSize.width/2 + 10)+ball.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2 - ball.contentSize.height/2);
[self addChild:ball];
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks for the response, well it looks like the bigger ball is now lower than the smaller ball. I thought that 0,0 put the ball in the bottom left. I'm not sure where I got that from though :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with cocos2d, but I'm assuming changing the position via `player.position` and `ball.position` is changing your `x` and `y` coordinates from 0 and 0 (set via `CGRectMake`) to coordinates based on the widths and heights of your sprites and window?

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work as is I just manually manipulated the y coordinate until I could figure out the correct positioning. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it this way, but I wouldn't.  Try using Box2D.  It is a fairly simple to use physics engine.  For what you want to do, it is very easy to use.

This site has a lot of great tutorials that can get you up to speed in no time:

[RayWenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Aaron, I'm curious, is Box2D a replacement for cocos2d? Why do you prefer it? I'm eventually going to try to make a much more complicated 2D game, with collision detection, multi-touch support, and 20+ sprites one the screen at once. Would you recommend me switching to Box2D, seems like I should start off with the best library :)

Comment: Box2D is a physics library that you use with Cocos2D.  There is also one called Chipmunk.  In order to do what you want to do (push an object with another object) all you have to do is create a shape for each object and then they will react to each other.  The site I linked is the best place for tutorials to help you with what you are doing right now.